# Parallel sql queries with mysql jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc, groovy

I have a test mysql database with 3 tables ('a', 'b', 'c'). If I select data from these tables consequentially it will take about 5 secs, if I ran the queries in parallel it still takes also 5 secs?

Where are no locks on worker threads in a Thread Dump.
Mysql server is out of the box.

```
@GrabResolver(name='gpars', root='http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/', m2Compatible=true)
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='0.12')
@Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.35')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)

import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool
import java.sql.DriverManager

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "test";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String sqlUsername = "root";
String sqlPassword = "";

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

def selectAll = { table ->

  def connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName,
      sqlUsername, sqlPassword);

  def stmt = connection.createStatement()
  String query = "select * from $table"
  def rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)

  def result = []

  while (rs.next()) {
    result << rs.getInt('Id')
  }

  rs.close()

  result
}

withPool(3) {
  ['a', 'b', 'c'].eachParallel { table ->
    selectAll(table)
  }
}
```

Comment: check this link: ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm1/mysql/news-and-events/newsletter/2003-04/a0000000154.html

Comment: How are you timing this?

Comment: measure System.nanoTime() at the start and end of the test